# Why UIDatePickerView is breaking the auto-layout after iOS14 in Xcode 12?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, xcode12

Hi I'm working on an iOS application in which i'm using the `UIDatePicker` for selecting Date. In Xcode 11, the `UIDatePicker` is showing as wheel style UI, in Xcode 12 the `UIDatePicker` as showing the new inline style. But the DatePicker is not laying out centrally. Please see the pictures for more clarity,
In Xcode 11:

[image]

In Xcode 12:

[image]

Why the DatePicker is showing in the left side, I gave the horizontally and vertically in container constraint. But still is not not centralize the `UIDatePicker`. Please help me.

Comment: Why not show the wheel style in iOS 14 too? Anyway that is not the inline style, it’s the compact style which is not appropriate to this interface. So set it to wheels or inline.

Comment: It is showing the wheel style if i set the UIDatePicker.style as .wheel. But I choose .automatic or .compact, in iOS 14 it shows the new design and below iOS 14 it shows the wheel style. And that is fine for me. But I need to centralize the UIDatePicker in the inline style. It is showing the left side.

Comment: Don't set it to automatic. That gives the compact style, and as you have discovered, it is not centered. Do what I suggested: use wheels or inline.

Answer (score 1):

```
datePickerBirth.maximumDate = NSDate() as Date
datePickerBirth.datePickerMode = .date;
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
   datePickerBirth.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Himanshu, I tried this, but still the UIDatePicker is not in the center of the view, see the above picture. I want the UIDatePicker to be the in center on inline style.

Comment: @Hilaj plese select storyboard datepicker in property automatic

Comment: It is already in automatic also i tried using if #available(iOS 14, *) {
   datePickerBirth.preferredDatePickerStyle = .automatic
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
datePicker.calendar = .current;
datePickerBirth.datePickerMode = .date;
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
   datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes